# Unable to upgrade python on cloudera hdfs

Tags: software-installation, hadoop

Not able to upgrade python on Cloudera as it shows the error whenever **I** run the below command:

```
$ sudo yum install python27
error: No package python27 available.

$ sudo yum install python36u
error: No package python36u available
```

I also run `yum install mrjob` but still not able to upgrade my python in cloudera.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo yum install python
$ sudo yum install python3
```

The first command will update python2. The second command will update python3

Comment: [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ sudo yum install python3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirrors.estointernet.in
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: centos.mirrors.estointernet.in
 * updates: centos.mirrors.estointernet.in
No package python3 available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: Do you get a list of `python3` packages after running `yum search python3`?  If not, you do not have any `yum` repositories configured with any Python 3.x packages.  The command `yum repolist` will show you the currently configured repositories.